# where to put shared mvc partial views?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an application that is split in to multiple controllers. However, a number of the views can be shared between the controllers. Normally I could include such in the Shared folder, but I feel at time this becomes a folder for pollution where everything gets dumped in there.

So for partial views, where is the best and normal place to include views shared between controllers? Should I continue to include them in the Shared folder or is ok to reference partial views in full views that do no exist in the same folder?

Answer (score 6):

Create subfolders in ~/Views/Shared if there is too much there.

Answer (score 0):

in the shared there are files like the MVC master page.
You can open a folder in the View folder, called shared Views...